# As I move through an object, i need to increase 1 digit as I create a url

Tags: iphone, ios4

Sorry but I cant think of how to word the question. This is what I am trying to do. I have an xml file that contains

```
<Image1>pic1.jpg</Image1>
<Image2>pic2.jpg</Image2>
<Image3>pic3.jpg</Image3>
<ImageCount>3</ImageCount>
```

I am creating a url to show the pic. As I click "next" to view the next image I need to create the next url. I know it would be something like this but I cant wrap my head around it this morning.

```
if (onImageCount <= totalImageCount) {


        //here we are on the second image request. we need to create a string to pass the "nextimageurl". this string points to which "Image1,2,3," xml tag to pull up next


        nextImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.pictureshostedhere.com/%@",selectedVehicle.Image[onImageCount]];
        imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nextImageURL]];
        carImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46,8,228,171)];
        carImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [scrollView addSubview:carImage];
        //[self.view sendSubviewToBack:carImage];
        [carImage release];
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: i dont think it would be a for loop. i already have the object created. now I just need to look at each string within that object, only as the user clicks "next image".

Comment: It looks like you need to increase onImageCount. UserClick->delegateEvent->increase onImageCount->calls the above method.

Comment: i increase the image count just about the if statement (in my project, not shown here sorry should have added that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps...

```
onImageCount++;
if (onImageCount <= totalImageCount) {
        nextImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.pictureshostedhere.com/%@",[self nextImageFromXML:onImageCount]];
       // Other stuff...
}
```

then, somewhere in your code:

```
-(NSStrng*)nextImageFromXML:(NSUInteger)count
{
   // Somewhere you've already parsed the XML into an Array
   return [xmlArray objectAtIndex:count];
}
```

The shortcut would be just...

```
 nextImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.pictureshostedhere.com/%@",[xmlArray objectAtIndex:onImageCount]]; // Where xmlArray returns the appropriate string
```

Comment: this would work, but the array is full of car objects. so your setup would return a car, instead of the cars image urls. Does that make sense? Inside the car object I have a bunch of strings. Price, make, model, pic1, pic2, etc....

Comment: OK, so once you grab the car object, increment a counter in car object for the next picture. To be honest, we can't read your mind, we can only go off of what you've posted. I believe there's a better way to do this though.

Comment: I agree jordan, sorry about the half ass question :) I am actually working on a solution that was based off of your answer. I am almost there I believe. Ill keep you posted. thanks for the input.